# How can you catch a custom exception from Celery worker, or stop it being prefixed with `celery.backends.base`?

Tags: python, exception, celery

My Celery task raises a custom exception `NonTransientProcessingError`, which is then caught by `AsyncResult.get()`. Tasks.py:

```
class NonTransientProcessingError(Exception):
    pass

@shared_task()
def throw_exception():
    raise NonTransientProcessingError('Error raised by POC model for test purposes')
```

In the Python console:

```
from my_app.tasks import *
r = throw_exception.apply_async()
try:
    r.get()
except NonTransientProcessingError as e:
    print('caught NonTrans in type specific except clause')
```

But my custom exception is **`my_app.tasks.`**`NonTransientProcessingError`, whereas the exception raised by `AsyncResult.get()` is **`celery.backends.base.`**`NonTransientProcessingError`, so my `except` clause fails.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/...venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 175, in get
    raise meta['result']
celery.backends.base.NonTransientProcessingError: Error raised by POC model for test purposes
```

If I catch the exception within the task, it works fine. It is only when the exception is raised to the `.get()` call that it is renamed.

How can I raise a custom exception and catch it correctly?

I have confirmed that the same happens when I define a `Task` class and raise the custom exception in its `on_failure` method. The following does work:

```
try:
    r.get()
except Exception as e:
    if type(e).__name__ == 'NonTransientProcessingError':
        print('specific exception identified')
    else:
        print('caught generic but not identified')
```

Outputs:

```
specific exception identified
```

But this can't be the best way of doing this? Ideally I'd like to catch exception superclasses for categories of behaviour.

I'm using Django 1.8.6, Python 3.5 and Celery 3.1.18, with a Redis 3.1.18, Python redis lib 2.10.3 backend.

Answer (score 6):

```
import celery
from celery import shared_task


class NonTransientProcessingError(Exception):
    pass


class CeleryTask(celery.Task):

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        if isinstance(exc, NonTransientProcessingError):
            """
            deal with NonTransientProcessingError
            """
            pass

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


@shared_task(base=CeleryTask)
def add(x, y):
    raise NonTransientProcessingError
```

Use a base Task with on_failure callback to catch custom exception.

Comment: Thanks. Does this code run on the worker? Great suggestion possibly for others coming across this post, but I'm looking for a way of catching the exception via the broker.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit late, but I have a solution to solve this issue. Not sure if it is the best one, but it solved my problem at least.

I had the same issue. I wanted to catch the exception produced in the celery task, but the result was of the class `celery.backends.base.CustomException`. The solution is in the following form:

```py
import celery, time
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from celery.states import FAILURE


def reraise_celery_exception(info):
    exec("raise {class_name}('{message}')".format(class_name=info.__class__.__name__, message=info.__str__()))


class CustomException(Exception):
    pass


@celery.task(name="test")
def test():
    time.sleep(10)
    raise CustomException("Exception is raised!")


def run_test():
    task = test.delay()
    return task.id


def get_result(id):
    task = AsyncResult(id)

    if task.state == FAILURE:
        reraise_celery_exception(task.info)
```

In this case you prevent your program from raising `celery.backends.base.CustomException`, and force it to raise the right exception.

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm not sure `exec()` is much of an improvement on string-matching on name, as I do in the question. Also do the exceptions have to be declared in the same module? I guess Celery is doing something like this though to raise after deserialization.