# Django with Celery and RabbitMQ

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I am working an application where I have to send emails asynchronously using Celery and RabbitMQ. How can I check if worker has sent email or failed?

Comment: yes it's possible

Answer (score 0):

[This SO explains what you are looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9034974/454023)

Basically, Below is the what you need to do.

```
task_id = uuid()
result = sendemail.apply_async((), task_id=task_id)
Now you know exactly what the task_id is and can now use it to get the AsyncResult:

# grab the AsyncResult 
result = celery.result.AsyncResult(task_id)

# print the task id
print result.task_id
09dad9cf-c9fa-4aee-933f-ff54dae39bdf

# print the AsyncResult's status
print result.status
SUCCESS

# print the result returned 
print result.result
'Email sent successfully'
```

Comment: Thanks will try it out