# Celery | Flask error: expected a bytes-like object, AsyncResult found

Tags: python, flask, celery, typeerror, celery-task

I am currently working on a flask application (Python 3.6) and wanted to integrate celery because I have multiple long running background tasks.

Edit: Celery 4.1

The integration was no problem and the celery tasks are executed correctly, but I cannot access the current state of a running task.

Celery, Flask setup:

```
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name,
                    backend=app.config["result_backend"],
                    broker=app.config["broker_url"])

    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["broker_url"] = "redis://localhost:6379"
app.config["result_backend"] = "redis://localhost:6379"
app.config["DB"] = "../pyhodl.sqlite"

celery_app = make_celery(app)
```

Celery task:

```
@celery_app.task(bind=True, name="server.tasks.update_trading_pair")
def update_trading_pair(self, exchange, currency_a, currency_b):
    print(exchange, currency_a, currency_b)
    time.sleep(50)
```

Call the task and store the value in a dictionary:

```
task_id = update_trading_pair.delay(exchange, currency_a, currency_b)
print("NEW TASK")
print(task_id)
id = exchange_mnemonic + "_" + currency_a + "_" + currency_b
TASK_STATES[id] = task_id
```

Get state of a task:

```
result = update_trading_pair.AsyncResult(TASK_STATES[market.__id__()])
print(result.state)
print(result) # works but only prints the task_id
```

This is were the error is raised. When i print only the result object it simply prints the task_id. And if I try to retrieve the current state i raises following exception:

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, AsyncResult found
```

Comment: what about `print(result.status)`

Comment: raises the same error

Comment: Have a look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034091/how-to-check-task-status-in-celery  Hope it helps

Comment: I allready read that question. My problem is that I can't even access the properties of the AsyncResult because the error is raised. I can't even call result.ready(), result.get() or any other Method. Although when I check for the result type with type(result) it say it is a "celery.result.AsyncResult". The error says the same AsyncResult found therefore the exception doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EXPLANATION :**

When you call your task :

```
task_id = update_trading_pair.delay(exchange, currency_a, currency_b)
```

your variable `task_id` is an instance of `AsyncResult`, it is not a string.

So, your variable `TASK_STATES[market.__id__()]` is also an instance of `AsyncResult` whereas it should be a string.

And then your are trying to instantiate an `AsyncResult` object with it

```
result = update_trading_pair.AsyncResult(TASK_STATES[market.__id__()])
```

So you are instantiating an `AsyncResult` object with another `AsyncResult` object whereas it should be instantiated with a string.

Maybe your confusion comes from your `print(task_id)` which shows you a string, but when you do this, under the hood the `__str__` method of the `AsyncResult` object is called and if you look at it in the source code [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/result.html#AsyncResult),

```
def __str__(self):
    """`str(self) -> self.id`."""
    return str(self.id)
```

it justs print the `id` attribute of your `task_id` object.

**SOLUTION :**

You can fix it with either by doing `TASK_STATES[id] = task_id.id` or by doing

```
result = update_trading_pair.AsyncResult(str(TASK_STATES[market.__id__()]))
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the exact problem. I thought that somewhere I read that delay() returns only the id. A look into the documentation would have solved the problem. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html