# Celery, Flower, Redis results

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery, flower

I am using recent versions of [Celery](https://github.com/celery/celery) and [Flower](https://github.com/mher/flower) and [Redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis), but I cannot understand what is happening.  I get all the results to work and the data is coming back correctly, but when I view the Celery Tasks with Flower, I see all the tasks and the results.

My task has the following decorator:

```
@celery.task(ignore_result=True, bind=True)
def perform_long_task(self, urls):
```

I've tried calling `get()`, `forget()`, etc but when I look at Flower the results are always there.

I've also tried:

```
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=10
```

I launch the task with:

```
celery worker -l info -B -A test.api.tasks
```

I've tried:

```
class CeleryConfig:
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'check-every-minute': {
                    'task': 'celery.backend_cleanup',
                    'schedule': crontab(hour="*/1"),
        }
    }
```

I cannot get the taks to not show in Flower, so I am thinking that the tasks must still be there (taking up memory).

Is this true?  Any thought to get them to disappear?

Thanks!

Comment: Recently I faced a similar problem with the `task_results` in celery. In my case the GC never cleaned up the memory when a `GroupResult` and `AsyncResult` was returned. Calling `.forget()` on them worked (meta data got deleted from my Redis), but the `GroupResult` was still persistent in memory. The only solution I have found, was to not use a `results_backend` and built my own implementation of the `task_result`. I'm not sure if you need the `task_results`. If you do you can store the goal of your task instead of the `task_result` https://stackoverflow.com/a/38267978/2525104