# Task celery succeeded in 0.09006300568580627s: None

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a project where I use Django with celery and I noticed when a task has errors I always have that message :

`Task celery succeeded in 0.09006300568580627s: None`

So I understand the task is finished but sometimes there are errors and I have succeeded which is for me not true. Besides, I have None and no informations.

Do you know if it is possible to get more informations instead of None ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: None is the ouptut of your task, if you don't use result-backend it will be None...Use logging to show what you want in stdout

Comment: Yes but how can I do to get for instance success or error instead of None ? I precise I use RabbitMQ with celery

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9046208/6602608

Comment: How can I get the variable task ?

Answer (score 2):

what you return from the task get logged instead of None

```
def my_task():
   ....
   if all_good:
       return "success" 
   return "something went wrong"
```

Comment: I tried but this does not work