# How to inspect and cancel Celery tasks by task name

Tags: python, redis, celery

I'm using Celery (3.0.15) with Redis as a broker.

Is there a straightforward way to query the number of tasks with a given name that exist in a Celery queue?

And, as a followup, is there a way to cancel all tasks with a given name that exist in a Celery queue?

I've been through the [Monitoring and Management Guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html) and don't see a solution there.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
# Retrieve tasks
# Reference: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.events.state.html
query = celery.events.state.tasks_by_type(your_task_name)

# Kill tasks
# Reference: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoking-tasks
for uuid, task in query:
    celery.control.revoke(uuid, terminate=True)
```

Comment: This sounded promising, but I wasn't able to get any results.  I set `CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT` to `True` for my workers, but calls to `celery.events.State().tasks_by_type(...)` returns an empty list.

Comment: Uhm, try to use *directly* `celery.events.state.state`, as `celerymon` does. [See the source](https://github.com/celery/celerymon/blob/master/celerymon/handlers/api.py).

Comment: From the celery shell, `celery.events.state.state` still gives me an empty list.  Is there a missing step to initialize consuming from the event queue?

Comment: Ok, you're right: you need to feed `State` objects. Copy & paste  https://github.com/celery/celerymon/blob/master/celerymon/consumer.py#L7, then call `EventConsumer.start()`

Comment: I don't really get how this relates to the answer. When does the start stop? When memory is full?

Comment: This does not work. I get an `AttributeError: module 'celery.events' has no attribute 'state'` exception.

Answer (score 22):

There is one issue that earlier answers have not addressed and may throw off people if they are not aware of it.

Among those solutions already posted, I'd use [Danielle's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29788081/1906307) with one minor modification: I'd import the task into my file and use its `.name` attribute to get the task name to pass to `.tasks_by_type()`.

```
app.control.revoke(
    [uuid for uuid, _ in
     celery.events.state.State().tasks_by_type(task.name)])
```

**However, this solution will ignore those tasks that have been scheduled for future execution.** Like some people who commented on other answers, when I checked what `.tasks_by_type()` return I had an empty list. And indeed my queues were empty. But I knew that there were tasks scheduled to be executed in the future and *these* were my primary target. I could see them by executing `celery -A [app] inspect scheduled` but they were unaffected by the code above.

I managed to revoke the scheduled tasks by doing this:

```
app.control.revoke(
    [scheduled["request"]["id"] for scheduled in
     chain.from_iterable(app.control.inspect().scheduled()
                         .itervalues())])
```

`app.control.inspect().scheduled()` returns a dictionary whose keys are worker names and values are *lists* of scheduling information (hence, the need for `chain.from_iterable` which is imported from `itertools`). The task information is in the `"request"` field of the scheduling information and `"id"` contains the task id. Note that even after revocation, the scheduled task will still show among the scheduled tasks. Scheduled tasks that are revoked won't get removed from the list of scheduled tasks until their timers expire or until Celery performs some cleanup operation. (Restarting workers triggers such cleanup.)

Comment: is there any way to know using command that which tasks are schedule under cron ? like beat scheduler ?

Answer (score 6):

As usual with Celery, none of the answers here worked for me *at all*, so I did my usual thing and hacked together a solution that just inspects redis directly. Here we go...

```py
# First, get a list of tasks from redis:
import redis, json

r = redis.Redis(
    host=settings.REDIS_HOST,
    port=settings.REDIS_PORT,
    db=settings.REDIS_DATABASES['CELERY'],
)
l = r.lrange('celery', 0, -1)

# Now import the task you want so you can get its name
from my_django.tasks import my_task

# Now, import your celery app and iterate over all tasks 
# from redis and nuke the ones that have a matching name.
from my_django.celery_init import app
for task in l:
     task_headers = json.loads(task)['headers']
     task_name = task_headers["task"]
     if task_name == my_task.name:
         task_id = task_headers['id']
         print("Terminating: %s" % task_id)
         app.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

Note that revoking in this way might not revoke prefetched tasks, so you might not see results immediately.

Also, this answer doesn't support prioritized tasks. If you want to modify it to do that, you'll want some of the tips in [my other answer that hacks redis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420719/64911).

Comment: Great answer. Trying to get anything out of the celery cli is usually unsuccessful in my cases, but this answer immediately got me started!

Comment: Where do `my_django` and `my_task` come from? If I use celery with fastapi, how can I get any task by task name?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in one request:

```
app.control.revoke([
    uuid
    for uuid, _ in
    celery.events.state.State().tasks_by_type(task_name)
])
```

Comment: awesome one-liner solution

Comment: n.b., you have to use `State().tasks_by_type` for celery 4+.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `flower` provides monitoring:

https://github.com/mher/flower

> Real-time monitoring using Celery Events
>
> Task progress and history Ability to show task details (arguments,
>   start time, runtime, and more) Graphs and statistics Remote Control
>
> View worker status and statistics Shutdown and restart worker
>   instances Control worker pool size and autoscale settings View and
>   modify the queues a worker instance consumes from View currently
>   running tasks View scheduled tasks (ETA/countdown) View reserved and
>   revoked tasks Apply time and rate limits Configuration viewer Revoke
>   or terminate tasks HTTP API
>
> OpenID authentication