# How to get Task objects for scheduled celery tasks?

Tags: python, celery

This question is similar to [Retrieve list of tasks in a queue in Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544629/retrieve-list-of-tasks-in-a-queue-in-celery), but I'd like to obtain the actual `Task` objects (cf. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.events.state.html#celery.events.state.Task) rather than a dictionary representation.

When I do

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
i = inspect()
```

and then do `i.scheduled()` from the shell, I get a result like

```
In [75]: i.scheduled()
Out[75]: 
{'celery@Kurts-MacBook-Pro-3.local': [{'eta': '2019-08-01T01:31:37.843141+00:00',
   'priority': 6,
   'request': {'acknowledged': False,
    'args': "[126, 'Business Signup', {'actualCompanyName': 'Gilmore and Beck LLC', 'gigsEnabledRegionMapping': True, 'companyName': 'Gilmore and Beck LLC', 'companyRegionMapping': 'Lesliechester', 'companyId': 'ow9DMA8'}]",
    'delivery_info': {'exchange': '',
     'priority': 0,
     'redelivered': None,
     'routing_key': 'celery'},
    'hostname': 'celery@Kurts-MacBook-Pro-3.local',
    'id': '4ecdc400-8421-4a06-babc-98493362ec67',
    'kwargs': '{}',
    'name': 'backend.tasks.task_send_event_to_iterable',
    'time_start': None,
    'type': 'backend.tasks.task_send_event_to_iterable',
    'worker_pid': None}},
  {'eta': '2019-08-01T01:39:21.205879+00:00',
   'priority': 6,
   'request': {'acknowledged': False,
    'args': "('hyjomuz@mailinator.net',)",
    'delivery_info': {'exchange': '',
     'priority': 0,
     'redelivered': None,
     'routing_key': 'celery'},
    'hostname': 'celery@Kurts-MacBook-Pro-3.local',
    'id': '294910a3-2323-4fcf-9768-115c1a8c5e06',
    'kwargs': '{}',
    'name': 'backend.tasks.task_send_business_lead_notification',
    'time_start': None,
    'type': 'backend.tasks.task_send_business_lead_notification',
    'worker_pid': None}}]}
```

I would like to do a search through these tasks and conditionally revoke one. However, I would like iterate over the results and have the actual tasks handy, like in the example in [How to inspect and cancel Celery tasks by task name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575826/how-to-inspect-and-cancel-celery-tasks-by-task-name). But if I try to do `celery.events.state.State()`, I get no events:

```
In [76]: celery.events.state.State()
Out[76]: <State: events=0 tasks=0>
```

Is it possible to obtain the actual `Task` objects for scheduled tasks? In particular, I'm interested in obtaining the `args` without having to parse or try an `ast.literal_eval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can actually get the actual Task instance, but you can easily create [AsyncResult](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult) by simply instantiating it with the task ID you want to inspect, and you need (naturally) to pass the Celery application object to it too.

Some pseudo-code:

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from my.project.celeryapp import myapp

task_res = AsyncResult("9ed888fe-f6b6-4443-85d3-787c5c1b26b0", app=myapp)
print(task_res.state)
```