# Django Celery get task count

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I am currently using django with celery and everything works fine.

However I want to be able to give the users an opportunity to cancel a task if the server is overloaded by checking how many tasks are currently scheduled.

How can I achieve this ?

I am using redis as broker.

I just found this :
[Retrieve list of tasks in a queue in Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544629/retrieve-list-of-tasks-in-a-queue-in-celery)

It is somehow relate to my issue but I don't need to list the tasks , just count them :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If your broker is configured as `redis://localhost:6379/1`, and your tasks are submitted to the general `celery` queue, then you can get the length by the following means:

```
import redis
queue_name = "celery"
client = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=1)
length = client.llen(queue_name)
```

Or, from a shell script (good for monitors and such):

```
$ redis-cli -n 1 -h localhost -p 6379 llen celery
```

Comment: Even though this is a correct solution for the redis broker, please mark @stephen Fuhry's comment as the correct solution as it is broker agnostic.

Answer (score 33):

Here is how you can get the number of messages in a queue using celery that is broker-agnostic.

By using `connection_or_acquire`, you can minimize the number of open connections to your broker by utilizing celery's internal connection pooling.

```
celery = Celery(app)

with celery.connection_or_acquire() as conn:
    conn.default_channel.queue_declare(
        queue='my-queue', passive=True).message_count
```

You can also extend Celery to provide this functionality:

```
from celery import Celery as _Celery


class Celery(_Celery)

    def get_message_count(self, queue):
        '''
        Raises: amqp.exceptions.NotFound: if queue does not exist
        '''
        with self.connection_or_acquire() as conn:
            return conn.default_channel.queue_declare(
                queue=queue, passive=True).message_count


celery = Celery(app)
num_messages = celery.get_message_count('my-queue')
```

Comment: Please provide some kind of explanation too to support your answer.

Comment: @Lal Added some explanation of the approach - hope that helps!

Comment: amqp.exceptions.NotFound: Queue.declare: (404) NOT_FOUND - no queue 'default' in vhost '/'

Because my queue is not on '/' host it's on '/apples' host. How do I get to that host?

Comment: setting passive to 'False' also works and circumvents the 404 NOT FOUND issue.

Comment: @Mario that would end up creating the non-existing Exchange, though, which is most likely not desired

Comment: In the first example of:

with celery.connection_or_acquire() as conn:
    conn.default_channel.queue_declare(
        queue='my-queue', passive=True).message_count

How would you store the message count as a variable?

Answer (score 7):

If you have already configured redis in your app, you can try this:

```
from celery import Celery

QUEUE_NAME = 'celery'

celery = Celery(app)
client = celery.connection().channel().client

length = client.llen(QUEUE_NAME)
```

Comment: For redis, `client = app.broker_connection().channel().client`

Comment: This will create a new hanging Redis connection every time you run this code. You have to release the opened connection and channel.

Answer (score 6):

Get a redis client instance used by Celery, then check the queue length. Don't forget to release the connection every time you use it (use `.acquire`):

```
# Get a configured instance of celery:
from project.celery import app as celery_app

def get_celery_queue_len(queue_name):
    with celery_app.pool.acquire(block=True) as conn:
        return conn.default_channel.client.llen(queue_name)
```

Always acquire a connection from the pool, don't create it manually. Otherwise, your redis server will run out of connection slots and this will kill your other clients.

Answer (score 3):

I'll expand on the answer of @StephenFuhry around the not-found error, because more or less broker-agnostic way of retrieving queue length is beneficial even if Celery suggests to [mess with brokers directly](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#redis). In Celery 4 (with Redis broker) this error looks like:

```
ChannelError: Channel.queue_declare: (404) NOT_FOUND - no queue 'NAME' in vhost '/'
```

Observations:

1. `ChannelError` is a `kombu` exception (if fact, it's `amqp`'s and `kombu` "re-exports" it).
2. On Redis broker Celery/Kombu represent queues as Redis lists
3. Redis collection type keys are [removed whenever the collection becomes empty](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#automatic-creation-and-removal-of-keys)
4. If we look at what `queue_declare` does, it has [these lines](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/5b072fb1716b903af6542285db4b4834cb17ef28/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py#L518):

   ```
   if passive and not self._has_queue(queue, **kwargs):
       raise ChannelError(...)
   ```
5. Kombu Redis virtual transport's `_has_queue` is [this](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/5b072fb1716b903af6542285db4b4834cb17ef28/kombu/transport/redis.py#L826):

   ```
   def _has_queue(self, queue, **kwargs):
       with self.conn_or_acquire() as client:
           with client.pipeline() as pipe:
               for pri in self.priority_steps:
                   pipe = pipe.exists(self._q_for_pri(queue, pri))
               return any(pipe.execute())
   ```

The conclusion is that on a Redis broker `ChannelError` raised from `queue_declare` is okay (for an existing queue of course), and just means that the queue is empty.

Here's an example of how to output all active Celery queues' lengths (normally should be 0, unless your worker can't cope with the tasks).

```py
from kombu.exceptions import ChannelError

def get_queue_length(name):
    with celery_app.connection_or_acquire() as conn: 
        try:
            ok_nt = conn.default_channel.queue_declare(queue=name, passive=True)
        except ChannelError:
            return 0
        else:
            return ok_nt.message_count
        
for queue_info in celery_app.control.inspect().active_queues().values():
    print(queue_info[0]['name'], get_queue_length(queue_info[0]['name']))
```