# given a Redis Broker and a db-backend, where do Celery Task requests first get written to?

Tags: python, redis, celery

Is there anyway to interrogate either redis, celery or postgres, to track a task request before its completion?

#### config:

```
BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "django-db"

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

app = Celery(
   "someapp",
)
```

Now, after a while, the Table `django_celery_results_taskresult` has the tasks, with its id, task_id, task_name and result, among other things.

```
  id  |             task_name             | status  |           date_done
------+-----------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------
 2162 | someapp.pssystem.tasks.initialize | SUCCESS | 2019-07-16 16:55:41.101537-07
 2163 | someapp.pssecurity.tasks.flush    | SUCCESS | 2019-07-16 17:11:45.599822-07
 2164 | someapp.pssecurity.tasks.flush    | SUCCESS | 2019-07-16 17:18:49.798436-07
 2165 | someapp.pssecurity.tasks.flush    | SUCCESS | 2019-07-16 17:26:45.349578-07
 2166 | someapp.pssecurity.tasks.flush    | SUCCESS | 2019-07-16 17:31:49.27337-07
```

But that is only **after** the task has completed successfully or had an error.  I am essentially launching long-running batches, which can easily take 2-3 minutes and I'd like to be able to acknowledge that the task was launched and poll its status before completion.

If I got to **redis-cli**, things aren't very clear there either, this looks it has more to do with celery workers than anything else:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> select 0
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *celery*
1) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
2) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
3) "_kombu.binding.celery"
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
1) "worker.#\x06\x16\x06\x16celeryev.026d2bed-ebc8-4c8b-a8c1-732cd847b381"
2) "worker.#\x06\x16\x06\x16celeryev.2f6efd77-f931-4c01-b45f-000f3ab9f5bd"
3) "worker.#\x06\x16\x06\x16celeryev.c0da9ba7-31fd-4a6b-be62-685423c7b542"
4) "worker.#\x06\x16\x06\x16celeryev.09ece5fd-3a45-4912-9c0f-ea1f9e67c930"
5) "worker.#\x06\x16\x06\x16celeryev.ad784e1f-47ad-402f-8359-295c35138fba"
6) "worker.#\x06\x16\x06\x16celeryev.633275dc-a090-4c2f-9d18-1d6b2d00f8e5"
7) "worker.#\x06\x16\x06\x16celeryev.2ee3da5b-1d65-4f8c-b652-8907af7b6eb1"
8) "worker.#\x06\x16\x06\x16celeryev.617f6218-9382-4965-8d3e-c1ed70cf96e4"
9) "worker.#\x06\x16\x06\x16celeryev.64c9beef-2d35-418c-a562-b0a6f0c4054e"
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers "_kombu.binding.celery"
1) "celery\x06\x16\x06\x16celery"
```

#### versions:

```
postgres                  9.6
celery                    4.3.0
Django                    2.2.3
django-celery-results     1.0.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upvoted both above, but what ultimately worked, to get rows in `Table.django_celery_results_taskresult` as soon as task starts was to change the Celery configuration:

credit goes to : [Celery tasks, states and results](https://michalklich.com/posts/celery-task-backend/)

```
app = Celery("foo")
app.conf.update(task_track_started=True)  #  ✅
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to monitor tasks.

1. You can use `flower` to monitor the tasks. It's a realtime monitor and web admin for celery distributed task queue.
   https://github.com/mher/flower
2. Or You use [celery API](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-task-if-i-have-the-id-that-points-there) to fetch the task info.

   ```
   result = app.AsyncResult(task_id)
   ```

Comment: I've given you both an upvote, but the actual issue I was facing, not having rows in django_celery_results_taskresult, has to be addressed via a celery configuration switch that tells it to write **app = Celery("bemyerp")**  **app.conf.update(task_track_started=True)**

Answer (score 1):

Its depends a little on what the intent is, but you can go a couple of different routes:

1. [Signals](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html) - hooks that are called in different stages of the celery lifecycle. Example - log when a task completes
2. [Inspection](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html) - An api built into celery to see status of different tasks. This is what flower uses under the hood
3. [Redis API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631669/django-celery-get-task-count) - Use the python Redis implementation to inspect a given queue. This is similar to what you were doing on the cli, but I have linked some examples

Based on your use case I think that a combo of signals to track starting and the redis api for polling active could work.