# How to find the number of unprocessed messages in celery queue

Tags: django, redis, celery, message-queue, django-celery

For my heroku app, the memory keeps growing, and I think it is because the number of messages sent per unit time is more than number of messages processed by the worker. How can I keep a monitor on the number of unprocessed message at any given point of time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve list of tasks in a queue in Celery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544629/retrieve-list-of-tasks-in-a-queue-in-celery)

Answer (score 2):

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
```

From [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544629/retrieve-list-of-tasks-in-a-queue-in-celery)

If you need logging facilities, check out [flower](https://github.com/mher/flower)

Comment: Thanks, what I want is the number of messages and not the number of tasks (which inspect would give). There could be one single shared_task or PeriodicTask, but different parts of the app could call the same MySharedTask.delay() multiple times in different messages (all referring the same MySharedTask) ; or the same PeriodicTask could be fired every 1 second by the Celery Beat. I want to find out if more messages are being generated per unit time than being processed

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need this:

```
@celery.task(rate_limit='500/m')
def my_task():
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    r = requests.get(url)
```

`rate_limit='500/m'` can limit your tasks to operate 500 times in one minute.