# django+celery+redis,app. Control. Inspect ()

Tags: django, celery

Now I want to use the app. Control. Inspect () to collect the list of pending tasks, and the waiting time of task in the queue, don't know how to get and write the code, is there any relevant snippet that I can see ?Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve list of tasks in a queue in Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544629/retrieve-list-of-tasks-in-a-queue-in-celery)

Comment: I am doing a performance analysis related page. So use this information of the celery task.Yes,I have seen this method in the documentation. It seems that I can get the task list. Another problem is how to check the waiting time of the task in the queue? Thanks.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=revoke#inspecting-workers   I wrote the code with the document in my project, but I could not get the task information, but I can see it in flower, do you know why?