# Create celery task only if there is no such task running or scheduled

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a task in celery, which takes a long time (170-200 seconds).

```
@task
def long_operation():    
    foo() # long operation, 170-200 seconds
```

This function is idempotent in a way that does not alter the existing data and returns the same result for the same dataset. I want to create a new task only if there is no same task scheduled or already running.

```
def call_long_operation():
    # if not scheduled or already executing
    #then
    long_operation.delay()
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It was long time ago, and I might be wrong about details.

Technically you can inspect existing/scheduled tasks, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544629/retrieve-list-of-tasks-in-a-queue-in-celery

But I resolved this by splitting `long_operation` to the smaller chunks, and ensuring results are cached. Hope it helps!