# How to retrieve list of tasks in a queue in Celery?

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, celery

My goal is to retrieve active & reserved tasks on my Celery workers.

I'm using a Django-Celery-Redis framework.

As suggested here: [Retrieve list of tasks in a queue in Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544629/retrieve-list-of-tasks-in-a-queue-in-celery)

I have done this to retrieve the tasks:

```
from your_app.celery import app as my_app

i = my_app.control.inspect()
active_tasks = i.active()
reserved_tasks = i.reserved()
```

It works well under my local environment.

Online though (I'm using Heroku), it works 5% of the time & 95% of the time I get some errors.

I get two types of errors, that randomly appears:

```
raise ConnectionError(str(exc)) from exc
kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: Error 0 connecting to THE_REDIS_SERVER. Error.
```

Or I get a `None` response from my calls.

I tried to configure some timeouts because by default `control.inspect` has `timeout = 1.0`.

```
from your_app.celery import app as my_app

i = my_app.control.inspect(timeout = 4.0)
active_tasks = i.active()
reserved_tasks = i.reserved()
```

But still I get some connection errors.

Any ideas?