# Is there a function in celery for finding waiting messages in a queue?

Tags: celery

I'm writing a custom router, I want to push a message to the queue which has the min waiting messages.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544629/retrieve-list-of-tasks-in-a-queue-in-celery)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gave me some ideas